# How do I display data from the beginning of a file until the first occurrence of a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

How do I display data from the beginning of a file until the first occurrence of a regular expression?

For example, if I have a file that contains:

```
One
Two
Three
Bravo
Four 
Five
```

I want to start displaying the contents of the file starting at line 1 and stopping when I find the string "B*". So the output should look like this:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Answer (score 11):

`perl -pe 'last if /^B/' source.txt`

An explanation: the -p switch adds a loop around the code, turning it into this:

```
while ( <> ) {
    last if /^B.*/;  # The bit we provide
    print;
}
```

The last keyword exits the surrounding loop immediately if the condition holds - in this case, /^B/, which indicates that the line begins with a B.

Answer (score 7):

if its from the start of the file

```
awk '/^B/{exit}1' file
```

if you want to start from specific line number

```
awk '/^B/{exit}NR>=10' file # start from line 10
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sed -n '1,/^B/p'
```

Print from line 1 to /^B/ (inclusive).  *-n* suppresses default echo.

**Update:** Opps.... didn't want "Bravo", so instead the reverse action is needed ;-)

```
sed -n '/^B/,$!p'
```

/I3az/

Comment: Unfortunately, this prints including the "Bravo" line, while the question wants to exclude the "Bravo" line.

Comment: Arghh!... didn't read question correctly.  Updated with reverse action "!p" (ie. print!) for everything not between /^B/ and end of file.  Many thanks for spotting this ndim.

Comment: Ah. `!` modifies an address range such that it only matches where it would not match, and vice versa. It is still part of the address range. Well, `!` was new to me... thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: Wouldn't quit be better so it does not read further than needed? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947950/895245

Answer (score 5):

```
sed '/^B/,$d'
```

Read that as follows: Delete (`d`) all lines beginning with the first line that starts with a "B" (`/^B/`), up and until the last line (`$`).

Answer (score 3):

Some of the `sed` commands given by others will continue to unnecessarily process the input after the regex is found which could be quite slow for large input. This quits when the regex is found:

```
sed -n '/^Bravo/q;p'
```

Comment: You don't need -n and p in this case; if you're just going to quit when you find the match, you can use the default printing as your print:

    sed '/^Bravo/q'

Comment: @Felix: Yours prints "Bravo", mine does not. The OP's example output does not include "Bravo".

Answer (score 2):

in Perl:

```
perl -nle '/B.*/ && last; print; ' source.txt
```

Comment: /B.*/ will match anything containing a B, not starting with a B.

Comment: The question didn’t state that the ‘B’ should be at the start of a line.

Comment: The -p instead of the -n will automatically give you that print at the end. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing some answers I've received:

Print data starting at the first line, and continue until we find a match to the regex, then stop:

```
<command> | perl -n -e 'print "$_" if 1 ... /<regex>/;'
```

Print data starting at the first line, and continue until we find a match to the regex, BUT don't display the line that matches the regular expression:

```
<command> | perl -pe '/<regex>/ && exit;'
```

Doing it in sed:

```
<command> | sed -n '1,/<regex>/p'
```

Comment: The flip flop operator is one of my favorites, and this situation is one of the few times I get to use it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a variation on an answer in [perlfaq6](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq6.html): [How can I pull out lines between two patterns that are themselves on different lines?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How_can_I_pull_out_l).

---

You can use Perl's somewhat exotic .. operator (documented in perlop):

```
perl -ne 'print if /START/ .. /END/' file1 file2 ...
```

If you wanted text and not lines, you would use

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" while /START(.*?)END/gs' file1 file2 ...
```

But if you want nested occurrences of START through END, you'll run up against the problem described in the question in this section on matching balanced text.

Here's another example of using ..:

```
while (<>) {
    $in_header =   1  .. /^$/;
    $in_body   = /^$/ .. eof;
# now choose between them
} continue {
    $. = 0 if eof;  # fix $.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'last if /B/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is a possibilty, you could do something like this:

```
% perl -0ne 'if (/B.*/) { print $`; last }' INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Seems excessive to be reading a whole file into memory before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

one liner with basic shell commands:

```
head -`grep -n B file|head -1|cut -f1 -d":"` file
```